# Get height of the container on load and hover effect based on the height detected

Tags: jquery

Function need to solve - We need to get height of "content" class container. On mouse over to the image container parent "a" tag.  Hover effect to start from bottom : 0 to the height of the child "a" "content" class.

But, present behavior -- it goes until end of the "isotope-grid" height. It starts from bottom:0 to Top:0.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="isotope-grid" data-isotope-tile="{modifier:'large', order:{mobile:1, desktop:1}}">
  <a href="javascript:;">
    <div class="image">
      <picture>
        <img srcset="images/goodcare.png" alt="Reccommended">
      </picture>
      <img class="icon" src="images/icons/badge.png" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <a href="regional.html" class="content toggleLink" target="_top">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
      <p>Mauris vitae ipsum sit amet mauris sagittis tincidunt id id enim. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla facilisi. Donec imperdiet suscipit accumsan.</p>
    </a>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="isotope-grid" data-isotope-tile="{modifier:'large', order:{mobile:1, desktop:1}}">
  <a href="javascript:;">
    <div class="image">
      <picture>
        <img srcset="images/goodcare.png" alt="Reccommended">
      </picture>
      <img class="icon" src="images/icons/badge.png" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <a href="regional.html" class="content toggleLink" target="_top">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet2</h3>
      <p>Mauris vitae ipsum sit amet mauris sagittis tincidunt id id enim. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla facilisi. Donec imperdiet suscipit accumsan2.</p>
    </a>
  </a>
</div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
// on mouseenter large tiles
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.isotope-grid--large', function(e) {
    var jTarget = $(this).find('.content');
    var height = $(e.currentTarget).css("height");
    jTarget.stop().animate({
        height: height
    });
});

// on mouseleave large tiles
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.isotope-grid--large', function(e) {
    var jTarget = $(this).find('.content');
    var height = 110;
    if (!bMediumScreen) {
        height = $(e.currentTarget).height() - $($(e.currentTarget).find("img")[0]).height();
    }
    jTarget.stop().animate({
        height: height,
        bottom: "0"
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you share a fiddle, because I am not sure what you want to achieve..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the height of the child 'h3' to the height of the child 'p', then you will get the height for '.content':

```
var jTarget = $(this).find('.content');
var height = jTarget.children('h3').height() + jTarget.children('p').height();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to get height of the container on load.. i need effect for this isotope grid container. please check this linkas reference.. http://www.tokiomarine.com/sg/en/personal/discover.html  .. on mouse over the container.. it starts from bottom:0. but ends @ top

Comment: I can see it ends at the top of the image, is that not the intention?

Comment: If not, then where should it end?

Comment: On mouse over.. it should end, based on class "content" <a> which contains <h3><p>. sometimes it will be 5 lines to 10 lines.. it have to be dynamic

Comment: Thanks.. but still not working.. ".content" is postion absolute... no animation happening..